# How to call a function in android pull down.?

Tags: javascript, android

I have knowledge in javascript but zero knowledge Android

So i tried pulldown refresh code like this and it is working fine in web browser (Computer)

And when i push the same code in android app it is not working how can i achive this.

This is my function and js:

```
var mouseY = 0;
    var startMouseY = 0;
    $('body').on('mousedown', function (ev) {
        mouseY = ev.pageY;
        startMouseY = mouseY;
        $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
            if (e.pageY > mouseY) {
                var d = e.pageY - startMouseY;
                console.log("d: " + d);
                if (d >= 200 ) {
                    $("#loader").show();
                    GetSheetData();
                    //$("#loader").hide();
                }
                $('body').css('margin-top', d/4 + 'px');
            }
            else
            $(document).unbind("mousemove");
        });
    });
    $('body').on('mouseup', function () {
        $('body').css('margin-top', '0px');
        $(document).unbind("mousemove");
    });
    $('body').on('mouseleave', function () {

        $('body').css('margin-top', '0px');
        $(document).unbind("mousemove");
    });
```

i am trying to refresh page with this function:

```
GetSheetData();  but it not working in android app.
```

Comment: Try with [`touch events`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwil-IrQ4o_UAhUlR48KHfIhDZoQFgg3MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FTouch_events&usg=AFQjCNHBt7i3bMcCdshjBw1ntXnFx-UG-A&sig2=BDAXW7mhc7V9tUOijuAyuA)

Comment: Android provides SwipeToRefresh layout for this functionality. https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html